# How to connect PHP Nightrain with MySQL 5

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql5

I have developed Web Portal using PHP and next step is to convert web portal into Desktop Application.

I'm using PHP Nightrain for converting Web Portable to Desktop Application.
But problem is, I could not able to connect to MySql Database.

Please help!

Comment: That's too bad, but what do you expect us to do about it? You've provided no code, no error messages, just a vague symptom... so... here's a vague solution: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Yes you right. actually i'm very new to it and we can execute Php in it. I'm trying to connect MySql DB


using connection string 
`<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysql($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>`

Error is
Fatal error: Class 'mysql' not found in C:\Users\HPatil\Downloads\nightrain12\nightrain_4.0.0_Windows_32-bit\www\index.php on line 7

Comment: the `mysql` library has NEVER had an object interface. you probably want `mysqli`.

Comment: yes i have added mysqli then also its showing error :/

Comment: have you develop any project using PHP nightrain?